# Hot to call a function inside a child component.ts from a parent component.ts in Angular

Tags: angular

In **app.component.html** I print a list of **section.component.html**

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let section of sectionObjectList">
    <app-section [section]="section"></app-section>
  </div>
```

When the template is rendered, I want to call from **app.component.ts** (the parent) a function inside the first **section.component.ts** of the list (the children).

What's the correct way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Use @Output decorator

Comment: Thank you man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [@Output](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) decorator:

**Parent component:**

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let section of sectionObjectList">
    <app-section [section]="section" (callback)="childCallback($event)"></app-section>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
childCallback(event) {
 console.log("Event data: ",event);
}
```

**Child component:**

```
@Output() callback = new EventEmitter<string>();

someFuntion() {
  callback.emit(value);
}
```

[Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Use `ViewChild` for DOM manipulations (change the native HTML element), and use `input/output` for data binding and controlling the state of a child component from the parent to keep him isolated and stateless.

Comment: Your Wellcome, according to docs, this is the recommended option, happy coding

Comment: @Matt in my opinion ViewChild is recommended to use for DOM manipulations

Comment: Probably you are right. I read some articles confirming what you said. I'll adopt your solution. Thank you

Comment: If you want to dispatch a specific function in the first item, you can pass to it some flag, this way the child component will dispatch the function or not.

Answer (score 1):

In app.component.html:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let section of sectionObjectList">
    <app-section #section [section]="section"></app-section>
  </div>
```

In app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComonent {
 @ViewChild('section) sectionCmp: SectionComponent;

 someMethod() {
    if (this.sectionCmp) {
       this.sectionCmp.childMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a solution like this one, it seems cleaner than using an Emitter.